# Characters getting changed when stored in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing some unremarkable storage of HTML form elements into MySQL using PHP. The form describes names, occupations and addresses and am seeing some odd results, for example, all in the same form submission:
"Pro Tester" gets stored in MySQL as "Pro Tester" (fine, but)
"1 The Avenue" gets stored as "1+The+Avenue" and
"test29@point1.com" gets stored as "test29%40point1.com"

Any idea what's going on, why white spaces are treated inconsistently and why I can't store the strings in their original form?

These are some disparate code fragments from a large file that may help I hope, or only confuse.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function processtext($aword) {
    $aword=addSlashes($aword);
    $aword=strtolower($aword);
    $aword=ucwords($aword);
return $aword;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    $fname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $sname=$_POST["familyname"];
    $job=$_POST["job"];
    $address=$_POST["address"]; // also tried $address=urldecode($_POST["address"]) but makes no difference
    $country=$_POST["country"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];

    $fname=processtext($fname);
    $job=processtext($job);
    $address=processtext($address);
    $city=processtext($city);
    $country=processtext($country);
    $email=addSlashes($email);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO addressbook (fname, sname, number, job, address, country, email) VALUES ('$fname', '$sname', '$number', '$job', '$address', '$country', '$email')";
    $myresult = mysql_query($sql,$db);
```

Comment: you can use myql_real_escape_string($userInputVal) before adding into DB.

Comment: @Prava-MindfireSolutions This is not a quoting problem.

Comment: Is your data being stored from a GET or POST, or other? Pure PHP, JS?

Comment: It's stored from a POST - thank you. Meanwhile I will try to find 'some' code although I fear it won't help much.

Comment: Is there any Javascript involved, from Ajax?

Comment: No. No Javascript from Ajax (or anywhere else). Meanwhile I edited the original question to add some code extracts, and elsewhere a debug statement that suggests it goes into MySQL with white spaces intact.

Comment: This `preprocesstext` function is completely inadequate and doesn't protect you from [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). A permanent solution to this would be to update to 
[PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and use placeholders to represent your values, virtually eliminating the possibility of escaping problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being URL encoded somehow, not properly decoded when you're retrieving it from the incoming parameters, or the parameters themselves are doubly URL encoded.

Check how the parameters are coming in and how you're handling them. If you can amend the question with some sample code that would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: A debug right after the SQL statement is submitted looks like VALUES ('Testabc', 'Testxyz', '0435359603555552', 'Pro Tester', '1 The Avenue', 'Testville', etc etc, indicating (from an echo debug statement, that the +'s are not inserted at that stage, but on review, address has them, job does not.

Comment: How are you presenting those values? You should be HTML escaping them, not URL escaping them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the most extraordinary issue that was responsible for the 'apparent' problem. I was viewing the table changes with PHPMySQL, and doing a SQL Search to find the test entry, repeatedly. PHPMySQL was caching the result - a phenomena I've never seen it do before. Refreshing the browser didn't change it. It wasn't until I changed the test address from '1 The Avenue' to '2 The Avenue' that it refreshed and showed that I'd solved the '+' problem long ago.

Apologies to all for chasing what would be an insoluble problem from your perspective, and thank you for your thoughts and suggestions. Every little nudge made me rethink this, so obliquely you have all helped today. Thank you very much to everyone.